# Only keep the IDs based on the observations of the other variable

Tags: python, pandas

Current table

```
ID   date   sender   sum_sender 
A    Jan20     3         37
A    Feb20     7         37
A    Mar20     12        37
A    Apr20     15        37
B    Mar20     1         26
B    May20     10        26
B    Jun20     15        26
...
Y    Jan21     10        47
Y    Feb21     12        47
Y    Mar21     20        47
Y    Apr21     5         47
```

I have a panel-time series with many IDs. How do I only keep rows of observations with 10 highest values of sum_sender?

so if i want to keep the observations with 2 highest sum_sender values

desired table

```
ID   date   sender   sum_sender 
A    Jan20     3         37
A    Feb20     7         37
A    Mar20     12        37
A    Apr20     15        37
Y    Jan21     10        47
Y    Feb21     12        47
Y    Mar21     20        47
Y    Apr21     5         47
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nlargest`:

```
N = 10
out = df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['sum_sender'].nlargest(N).index.levels[1]]
```

Example for `N=2` with your sample:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['sum_sender'].nlargest(N).index.levels[1]]
  ID   date  sender  sum_sender
0  A  Jan20       3          37
1  A  Feb20       7          37
4  B  Mar20       1          26
5  B  May20      10          26
7  Y  Jan21      10          47
8  Y  Feb21      12          47
```

**Update**

If you need the top 10 of `sum_sender` independently of `ID`, you can simple use:

```
>>> df.nlargest(columns='sum_sender', n=10)
   ID   date  sender  sum_sender
7   Y  Jan21      10          47
8   Y  Feb21      12          47
9   Y  Mar21      20          47
10  Y  Apr21       5          47
0   A  Jan20       3          37
1   A  Feb20       7          37
2   A  Mar20      12          37
3   A  Apr20      15          37
4   B  Mar20       1          26
5   B  May20      10          26
```

**Update 2**
Try:

```
>>> df.loc[df['ID'].isin(df.groupby('ID').max().nlargest(2, 'sum_sender').index)]
   ID   date  sender  sum_sender
0   A  Jan20       3          37
1   A  Feb20       7          37
2   A  Mar20      12          37
3   A  Apr20      15          37
7   Y  Jan21      10          47
8   Y  Feb21      12          47
9   Y  Mar21      20          47
10  Y  Apr21       5          47
```

Comment: I had a little bit different proposal, but all depends whether the data set is a big or small ```df.sort_values(by = "sum_sender", ascending=False).head(10).copy()```. The solution from Corralien is much better in this case :)

Comment: @baskettaz. I don't know if it is per ID or on the entire dataframe.

Comment: my intention was to keep all the IDs with nth highest "sum_sender" values. So all observations from the same ID should be kept.. maybe i wasn't clear.

Comment: no neither. I edited the question.

Comment: Why `A    Apr20` disappears?

Comment: @Corralien you are the best, update2 was what i was looking for. thank you <3

Comment: @corralien one question, what if i want to only keep those from, let's say, the third largest to the tenth largest by sum_sender? not by largest. any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicates` in "sum_sender", then find the 2 largest values by `nlargest`, then use `isin` to filter:

```
largest_values = df['sum_sender'].drop_duplicates().nlargest(2)
out = df[df['sum_sender'].isin(largest_values)]
```

Output:

```
   ID   date  sender  sum_sender
0   A  Jan20       3          37
1   A  Feb20       7          37
2   A  Mar20      12          37
3   A  Apr20      15          37
7   Y  Jan21      10          47
8   Y  Feb21      12          47
9   Y  Mar21      20          47
10  Y  Apr21       5          47
```

Comment: Congrats @enke for your 10k!